# SSIS how to identify row delimiters

Tags: ssis

I am new to ssis, could anyone help me with my question please!!

I have a text file that i need to import in a table, but i am getting follow errors

```
[Flat File Source [26]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Column 4" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

[Flat File Source [26]] Error: The "output column "Column 4" (51)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Column 4" (51)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
```

My file has no column headers and is in the following format.

```
Joan;123mckel;st cloud;2;Leo;123avenue;maryland heights;3;
```

I need the above row to be inserted as two rows in the table

```
Joan;123mckel;st cloud;2
Leo;123avenue;maryland heights;3
```

Could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Source as is, Pass it through a `Multicast`, `Sorting` and `Merge` them back using only the first two columns. This way you will Merge column 0 to 5, 1 to 6, etc.